# how to delete list (todo) react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

how to delete list

```js
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";

export default function Home() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState("");

    const [list, setList] = useState([]);

    const handleChange = e => {
        setValue(e.target.value);
    };

    const addTask = () => {
        //list array deer value-iin utgiig nemeh

        const arraycopy = [...list, value];

        setList(arraycopy);

        console.log(list);
    };

    return (
        <div style={{}}>
            <div>
                <h4
                    style={{
                        width: "250px",
                        height: "50px",
                        backgroundColor: "#1C89B6",
                        color: "white"
                    }}
                >
                    My Todo list
                </h4>
            </div>

            {list.map((el, index) => {
                console.log(index, "==> ", el);

                return <p>{el}</p>;
            })}

            <input
                style={{ width: "200px", height: "30px", borderRadius: "20px" }}
                value={value}
                onChange={handleChange}
                placeholder="whats next?"
            />

            <button
                style={{
                    width: "100px",
                    height: "30px",
                    borderRadius: "20px",
                    display: "flex",
                    backgroundColor: "#1C89B6",
                    color: "white"
                }}
                onClick={() => addTask()}
            >
                <h4>add</h4>
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

how to do that delete thing

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function to delete it like so:

```
// this function will get the index provided by the map function
function deleteTodo(index){
// copy the list state 
const copy = [...list]

// At the position index delete 1 item 
copy.splice(index, 1); 

// set a new state to your list
setList(copy)
}
```

Your map function should be something like that:

```
{list.map((el, index) => {

    return <button onClick={()=> deleteTodo(index)}>{el}</button>

  })}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: @Hangai you should mark the answer as correct if it worked for you for better understanding of other users.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.filter to do this:

```
let arr = [1,2,3]

arr.filter((item)=>item!==2) // [1, 3]
```

Comment: Not sure if this is a good approach, if there is a repeted item it will be deleted as well.

Comment: You are absolutely right, it would remove multiple values if there was a duplicate item. However, if we knew the index of the item, we could do it this way.
arr.filter((_,index)=>index!==1)
After all,we need to know which item should be deleted.

Comment: Yeah, arr.filter((_,index)=>index!==1) sounds like a simple and effective solution.